# How can I test the procedure or oracle function?

Tags: oracle, testing, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to create a lots of procedure and function in oracle. I am using SQL developer tool. I am a Java professional. In java we can write Junit test cases to validate our code.

Is there any way to do that? Any help would be welcome.

Comment: You need to write scripts to test procedures or function in oracle

Answer (score 1):

*utPLSQL* is a unit-testing framework for PLSQL.

http://utplsql.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

do you mean to validate that the code compiles, or validate that it does what you expect? SQL Developer will show validation errors if there are compilation errors. But i suspect you mean validate the code functions as expected, in which case this link may help you  http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/sqldev_unit_test/sqldev_unit_test_otn.htm